# How to make hollow box using two for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

Use nested for loops statements to draw hallow boxes of "*"s. The boxes have the same number of rows and columns and this number should be input from the user (valid range: 5 to 21). I'm having trouble coming up with a way to make the box hollow. this is what i have for the code and it comes as a complete square, but i need it to be hollow or just the border.

```
System.out.println("How many rows/columns(5-21)?");
    rows=input.nextInt();
    while(rows<5||rows>21){
      System.out.println("Out of range. Reenter: ");
      rows=input.nextInt();
    }
    for(m=1;m<=rows;m++){
      for(c=1;c<=rows;c++){
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
```

the output should look like this:
How many rows/columns (5-21)? 25 
Out of range. Reenter: 7

```
******* 
*     * 
*     * 
*     * 
*     * 
*     *  
*******
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of an earlier question.  Just searching for it now ...

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) class?

Comment: Ooh, no, not quite the same question - but definitely the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309256/how-to-implement-lines-increasingly-with-constants - except that the OP keeps deleting bits out of the question.  No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print only some of the `*`s, so add a test before the `print("*")`.  One option would be to explicitly test the four conditions (top, bottom, left, right) and OR them together logically:

```
if( (m==1) ||     //top
    (m==rows) ||  //bottom
    (c==1) ||     //left
    (c==rows)     //right
) {
        System.out.print("*");
} else {
        System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Each `m==` test or `c==` test identifies one piece of the square.  Since the four tests
are ORed together, the if() is true (and a * is printed) if any one of the four tests is true.  If none of them are true, the `else` runs and prints a space.

I also recommend renaming `m` to `rowIndex` and `c` to `colIndex` or something.  When you come back to the code a week or two later, more descriptive names will make it easier to pick up where you left off.  (Ask me how I know!)

Comment: Since OP is a beginner, let's encourage them to { bracket } one-line blocks. Tempted to edit the answer myself -- but it's more polite to suggests it, right?

Comment: As well as descriptive variable names, I'd go a step further and recommend `boolean isTopOrBottomRow(row,height)` and `boolean isEdgeColumn(column, width)` methods. Good habits!

Comment: @slim good ideas!  I added the braces - feel free to add a better version :) .  The current answer attempts to be a drop-in to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class icibos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner gir = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Karenin kenarını girin: ");
        int kenar = gir.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= kenar; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= kenar; j++) {
                if (i == 1 || i == kenar || j == 1 || j == kenar)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int i=1;i<=lgh;i++){
        for (int a=1;a<=lgh;a++){
            if(i>1 && i<lgh && a>1 && a<lgh)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this , its bit hard code.**

Working Example [here](http://ideone.com/n0LWEP)

```
    String myStars="*******";
    String oneStar="*";
    int count=0;

    System.out.println(myStars);
    count++;
    while(count<=7)
    {
        System.out.println(oneStar+"     "+oneStar);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.print(myStars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Example is [Here](http://ideone.com/tX1eT1)

```
    String pattern;

    int noOfTimes;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the pattern to print : ");
    pattern = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter number of times it should get printed : ");
    noOfTimes = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int i=1; i<=noOfTimes; i++) {      

        System.out.println();

        if(i==1 || i==noOfTimes) {

            for(int j=1; j<=noOfTimes; j++){

                System.out.print(pattern+" ");

            }
        }
        else {

            for(int k=1; k<=noOfTimes;k++) {

                if(k==1 || k == noOfTimes) {

                    System.out.print(pattern + " ");

                }                   
                else {

                    System.out.print("  ");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class holsqr{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner ma=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int max=ma.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=max;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=max;j++){
                if((i==1)||(i==max)){
                    System.out.print("#");
                }else{
                    if(j==1||j==max){
                        System.out.print("#");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }           
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It pretty simple, using two while loop:
 public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int size = 0;
    int r = 0;
    String star = "*";
    String space = " ";
    System.out.print("Input size of side of square: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    size = input.nextInt();

    while (r < size) {
        int c = 0;
        while (c < size) {
            System.out.print(r > 0 && r < size - 1 && c > 0 && c < size - 1 ? space : star);
            ++c;
        }
           System.out.println();
        ++r;
    }
}
```