# Generating Dynamic Square Pattern [Python Programming Language]

Tags: python

I've been tasked to create a simple application using python that will allows me to enter an integer which will then generate a series of pattern in an infinite loop.

Example #1: 3

Output:

```
xxx
x.x
xxx

...
.x.
...

...
...
...

...
.x.
...

xxx
x.x
xxx

(Cont.)
```

Example #2: 6

Output:

```
xxxxxx
x....x
x....x
x....x
x....x
xxxxxx

......
.xxxx.
.x..x.
.x..x.
.xxxx.
......

......
......
..xx..
..xx..
......
......

......
......
......
......
......
......

......
......
..xx..
..xx..
......
......

(Cont.)
```

---

Here are my codes so far.

```
import time
time.sleep(0.5)

#n = int(input("input pattern size: "))
n=3
i=n
j=n
if(n < 3):
    while(n < 3):
        print("warning: pattern size should be at least 3!")
        n = int(input("input pattern size: "))

        if(n >= 3):
            #INSERT ELSE CODE HERE#
            break;

else:
    while(n >= 3):
        for i in range (i, 0, -1):
            for j in range(j, 0, -1):
                print('x' * j)
                break;
        break
```

Thanks for all the help I can get, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) prompt for a value >= 3, then display an error message and exit if they put a value < 3.

2) consider that you're drawing a square (a 2 dimensional array) so you should parse X rows and columns (IOW, assign the users input value to X & Y and then iterate through Y for X times or X for Y times)

3) You haven't given much information about the display pattern, but think about building said pattern first and then printing it out (sorry, that's not very clear - let me think about another way to say it)
**addenda - there are going to be a boatload of permutations, even @ 6x6 - you may only need to show your logic, running the program could take a very long time**

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information and thanks for helping me out!

1) I'll be adding this validation right after I've completed the main program

2) I'm only suppose to use loops for this exercise (No Strings, No Array, No Function) 

3) A perfect example for my example is somewhat alike:

[Link-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352683/print-a-pattern-to-display-numbers-up-to-5-rows-and-5-columns-like-5-4-3-2-1-and)


And.

[Link-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393842/how-to-make-hollow-box-using-two-for-loops)